# Regex to find lines that start with /*

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I need a regular expression to find all the lines that begins with `/*`

```
$num_queries =  preg_match_all(
    'REG_EXP',
    file_get_contents(__DIR__ . DIR_PLANTILLAS . '/' . 'temp_template.sql')
);
```

I try this `'^\/\*.*'`  but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this string: `/^\/\*.*/` in the [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function, it'll work. This pattern matches `/*` followed by *maybe* some text.
Make sure the regular expression will be performed on each line. I recommend that you first split the string (file contents) by a newline. You can use the function [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) in order to do so.

If you don't want to split the file contents by each line first, then you can use the following pattern: `/(^|\n)\/\*(.*)/`. That pattern matches first either the beginning of the string or a newline, followed by `/*`, followed by *maybe* some text.

Notice that in the patterns `/^\/\*.*/` and `/(^|\n)\/\*(.*)/` the `/` is used as delimiter. That means that further occurences of `/` must be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
^\/\*+[^\n]*$
```

Edit: correction re escaping the `/`

Comment: What about the start and end delimiters?

Comment: @mmmshuddup Yup. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Please, note, what you deal with multiline content, but ^ means beginning of content, not a beginning of a line.
try `(\/[^\r\n]+)[\r\n$]+`